# Unity Shuriken: Make Particle System Completely Scale

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a bit of an issue. In my game I need my entire map to be able to scale up or down, this means the particle systems do too. Some are local and some are world space. Is there any way to make it so that the same system scaled 10x as big would look exactly the same as the original but 10x the size? this means the velocities, gravity, dampening etc would also scale

Comment: Could you not move the camera?

Comment: No, this isn't the only thing in the game

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to move the map into a different scene and then render the game and the map on screen at the same time? With the Scene changes that were done a while back this might now be possible.

Comment: Seems like itd be a lot less performant wouldnt it? and more of a hassle

Comment: Depends how it was implemented... Would it not be possible for you to put all of the map stuff under a gameobject and then scale that game object when you need too?

Comment: I could, but then the particle systems end up looking different. thats the thing, I need a way for a particle system to behave as if it was zoomed out if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a script and place it on your ParticleSystem game objects.

```c#
class ParticleSystemScaler : Monobehaviour
{
    ParticleSystem _ps;
    public float sizeModifier = 1.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        _ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        //For each property you want to scale, just multiply it by the size modifier.
        _ps.startSize *= sizeModifier;
    }
}
```

You could improve this in a few ways..

1. Store the sizeModifier in some `GameManager` type class, and retrieve it when it is needed
2. Cache the original values on awake into some floats, and do `originalStartSize *= sizeModifier`
3. Make some function `ResizeParticles(float modifier)` that can be called instead of doing the resize on awake.

Those improvements will enable you to call `ResizeParticles()` at any moment and have the 'modifier' applied to their original sizes (that would have been copied from the components themselves on awake)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Bejasc's answer, I've made a bit more comprehensive and automated version, however there are definitely parameters I haven't added yet

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleSystemScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ParticleSystem ThisSystem;
    private ParticleSystem.MainModule ThisMain;
    private ParticleSystem.NoiseModule ThisNoise;
    private ParticleSystem.LimitVelocityOverLifetimeModule ThisLimitVelocity;

    private float CurrentScale;

    private float InitialGravity;
    private float InitialNoiseStrength;
    private float InitialNoiseFrequency;
    private float InitialMaxVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        Initialise();
        ResizeSystem(transform.lossyScale.x);
    }

    private void Initialise()
    {
        ThisSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

        if (ThisSystem)
        {
            ThisMain = ThisSystem.main;
            ThisNoise = ThisSystem.noise;
            ThisLimitVelocity = ThisSystem.limitVelocityOverLifetime;

            InitialGravity = ThisMain.gravityModifierMultiplier;
            InitialNoiseStrength = ThisNoise.strengthMultiplier;
            InitialNoiseFrequency = ThisNoise.frequency;
            InitialMaxVelocity = ThisLimitVelocity.limitMultiplier;
        }
    }

    private void ResizeSystem(float NewScale)
    {
        CurrentScale = NewScale;

        if (ThisSystem)
        {
            ThisMain.gravityModifierMultiplier = InitialGravity * NewScale;
            if (ThisMain.simulationSpace == ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World)
            {
                ThisNoise.strengthMultiplier = InitialNoiseStrength * NewScale;
                ThisNoise.frequency = InitialNoiseFrequency / NewScale;
                ThisLimitVelocity.limitMultiplier = InitialMaxVelocity * NewScale;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.lossyScale.x != CurrentScale) { ResizeSystem(transform.lossyScale.x); }
    }
}
```